# how do i create rows from an arraylist of object classes in android studios?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im trying to create a bunch of rows in a Listview to show from an ArrayList of object class

my object class Locations has

```
    private String name;
    private int currentCapacity;
    private int maxCapacity;
    private int id; 

    public Locations(String name, int currentCapacity, int maxCapacity, int id){
    this.currentCapacity = currentCapacity;
    this.id = id;
    this.maxCapacity = maxCapacity;
    this.name = name;
    }
```

```
    Locations loc1 = new Locations("foodplace", 10, 100, 1);
    Locations loc2 = new Locations("area", 15, 25, 2);
    Locations loc3 = new Locations("otherplace", 25, 25, 3);
    locationsArrayList.add(loc1);
    locationsArrayList.add(loc2);
    locationsArrayList.add(loc3);

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.theList);

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, locationsArrayList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

how do i input my ArrayList such that i can change the color of the row based on the currentCapacity and show the name on the block?

Comment: You can create a custom adapter using RecyclerView.Adapter. Plenty of examples out there. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use RecyclerView

```
//Declare some items in your ArrayList
Locations loc1 = new Locations("foodplace", 10, 100, 1);
Locations loc2 = new Locations("area", 15, 25, 2);
Locations loc3 = new Locations("otherplace", 25, 25, 3);
locationsArrayList.add(loc1);
locationsArrayList.add(loc2);
locationsArrayList.add(loc3);

//make your own adapter class which extend RecyclerView.Adapter
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(locationsArrayList,this);
 
//setup your RecylerView
recyclerView.setAdapter(itemsListAdapter);
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

Now in your Adapter class you can change each item color or font... based on ArrayList attribute.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

    private ArrayList<Location> locationsArrayList;
    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<Location> locationsArrayList, Context context) {
        this.locationsArrayList= locationsArrayList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_layout,parent,false));
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) holder;
//here you can set your own conditions based on your arraylist using position parameter
        viewHolder.itemNameTextView.setText(locationsArrayList.get(position).getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return locationsArrayList.size();
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //setup item layout attributes
        TextView itemNameTextView;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemNameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemNameTextView);
        }
    }
}
```

I know it's complicated but RecyclerView make your list more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Hie i would suggest you use `RecyclerView` to achieve your list view

if you are using gradle for your dependencies you need to implement it in your app level gradle file

In your `activity.xml` file you implement like this

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/locations_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And then create a item file that will represent item in a list item

for example lets call it `location_list_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/location_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/max_capacity"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/current_capacity"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
   
</LinearLayout>
```

Then after that you would need to implement an Adapter lets call it `LocationAdapter.java`

```
    public class LocationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LocationAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        ArrayList<Location> locations;//list of locations
        public LoacationAdapter(ArrayList<Location> locations) {
            this.locations = locations //initialising list in constructor
        }
    
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Locations.Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
//here this method inflates the row view
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.location_list_item, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull LocationAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {  
//this method sets values in the views  
    holder.locationName.settext(locations.get(position).getLocationName())
    holder.maxCapacity.settext(locations.get(position).getMaxCapacity())
 holder.currentCapacity.settext(locations.get(position).getCurrentCapacity())
        }
    
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return locatioins.size();// number of locations
        }
    
//this class will repressent the list item
        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
// this are the views in the list item
            TextView locationName, maxCapacity, currrentCapacity;
            public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                locationName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.location_name);
                maxCapacity= itemView.findViewById(R.id.max_capacity);
                currentCapacity= itemView.findViewById(R.id.current_capacity);
                itemView.setOnClickListener(this::onClick);
    
            }
    
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               //do what ever you want when an item is clicked
            }
        }
    }
```

In  in your  activity file then

```
ArrayList<Location> locationsArraylist = new ArrayLists<> ();
//initializing recylcer view 
RecyclerView  locationList =  findViewById(R.id.locations_list);
// setting layout manager
locationsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext, RecyclerView.Vertical, false));
//setting adapter  adapter with the list of locations you want to display
locationList.setAdapter(new LocationsAdapter(locationsArraylist));
```